# devbridge autocomplete query AJAX implementation

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I'm getting trouble with [devbridge autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) in my form

my **header** section:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

**page with input fields** looks like this:

```
<script>
$('#client_recommendation').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/ClientRecommendation.php',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
</script>

<form action="/scripts/add_client.php" method="post" name="add_client">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="client_recommendation">Recommendation:</label>
        <input name="client_recommendation" size="25" type="text" id="client_recommendation" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**ClientRecommendation.php**

```
require '../scripts/connect.php';

$cr  = trim($_GET['client_recommendation']); //also tried trim($_GET['query']);


    $sql = "SELECT  client_name, client_id
                          FROM (
                            SELECT CONCAT(
                                client_name, ' ', client_surname, IF(
                                    LENGTH(client_prompt), 
                                    CONCAT(' (',client_prompt,')'), '')
                                )
                            AS client_name, client_id
                            FROM `clients`
                          ) 
                          clients 
                          WHERE client_name LIKE '%" . $cr . "%' 
                          ORDER BY client_name";

    $result = $conn->query($sql); 
    $reply = array();
    $reply['query'] = $cr;
    $reply['suggestions'] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $reply['suggestions'][]=$row['client_name'];

    }

    echo json_encode($reply);

    $conn->close();
```

as a test i tried this:

```
$cr  = "pa";
```

and the `ClientRecommendation.php` returns correct result:

```
{"query":"pa","suggestions":["Pavlo hryhorash"]}
```

which is valid JSON, but in my form I get nothing.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**
I added `$(document).ready` to the script in page with input fields:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#client_recommendation').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/ClientRecommendation.php',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value);
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

After that the generated HTML markup for suggestions started to load with the page, and while typing in the input field I see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
m.parseJSON @ jquery.min.js:4g.transformResult @ 
jquery.autocomplete.min.js:49(anonymous function) @  
jquery.autocomplete.min.js:288j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2x @ 
jquery.min.js:4b @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was rather stupid, but maybe it will be helpfull for someone.
In my `connect.php` there was this string:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "<!--Connected successfully !-->";
```

And this `echo` blocked the script. I just commented it and everything is fine now